# Create a single jbossall-client.jar bundle in JBoss 5.0.x?

Tags: java, jboss

Since JBoss 5.0.0, jbossall-client.jar only contains a manifest that points to all the jars in the client directory.  Is there any way to create a jbossall-client.jar that contains all of these classes instead of having to put the 70 or so individual jars on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining all client jars to a single jar may not be recommended. However if you are keen to see a single jar with all classes loaded in it one approach would be to write an ant script which can unjar the required jars to a temp dir and then make a single jar of the classes in the temp dir.

```
   <target name="unjar.jar">
        <unjar dest="${temp.dir}">
              <patternset>
                    <include name="**/*.class" />
              </patternset>
              <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
              </fileset>
        </unjar>
  </target>


  <target name="combine.jar" depends="unjar.jar">
        <jar jarfile="${base.dir}/${jar.filename}"
              basedir="${temp.dir}" includes="**/*.class" update="true"
              compress="false">
        </jar>
        <delete dir="${temp.dir}" quiet="true" />
  </target>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that they decided to use the manifest method to allow users to swap out individual jars if necessary.  However, they used to create a single jar client and other app servers such as Weblogic have a JarBuilder tool to accomplish this. I think your method may do the trick, thanks.